# Wordpress PHP How to Get a Function's Return Value Into an If() Statemente

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to create and if() statement that works in accordance to the kind of post (i.e., page or article) and, if page, the title of such page.

The type of post can be obtained from its class function `post_class()` and the title from its title function `the_title()`.

So I know where I can get the info I need but, then, no matter what, I cannot turn this info into a string I can test. Wherever I put any of these two functions I get an output onto the page.

First, I tried:

```
if(strpos(post_class(), 'page')) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Didn't work. Just had the `post_class()` dumped onto the page.

Then, I tried calling the function as the value of a variable:

```
$this_class = post_class();
```

And had the same result.

I've since tried a couple of other *dirtier* ways of doing it but to no avail. It seems wherever these WP functions are placed, they will dump their values onto the page.

Perhaps somebody out there knows how I can successfully get the type of post and title and set them to if() statements in order to trigger whatever else.

Thanks!

Comment: `post_class` prints the value, `get_post_class` returns the value.

Comment: Hey! That does it! Thanks!

Comment: Would it be ok if I would write it as an answer?

Comment: Do you want to add it as an Answer or should I do it on your behalf?

Comment: Yes, perfect! (Answer to your previous question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wordpress Docs:

**[post_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class)**

> When the post_class function is added to a tag within the loop, for
>   example  >, it will **print** out and add
>   various post-related classes to the div tag.

In case you would like to be able to retrieve the value you should use
the **[get_post_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_class)** function which returns that value.

> Retrieve the classes for the post div as an array.

Comment: Perfect, Ofir, this does it! Thanks a lot for the quick and accurate response!